# ngTransclude in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and in learning stage, i have come across ngTransclude, when i start reading the document http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude, i could able to get , what that really does,

Can any of you guys, please tell me what actually ngTransclude does, And what is the change when it is included, when when it is not included in directive.

Please give me a clear understanding of ngTransclude, and how important is, and when we can use it.

Comment: Here's one of the better explanations I've found on the net: [link](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-transclusion-basics). If you're new to AngularJS I highly recommend taking a look at the rest of the videos on [egghead.io](https://egghead.io). They are very clear and informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I Just Want To See It Working:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/liRDIEy9sWoSPSHJ1oln?p=preview

**Explanation Of The Example**

Think of "ngTransclude" as saying "keep whatever is inside of this element, inside of the element, even after I rewrite it". It is most used with directives. Take the following as an example, I defined a directive "emphasize-text" which really just is going to wrap whatever I am provided in an "h1" element. The following is that directive:

```
app.directive("emphasizeText", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<h1 ng-transclude></h1>',
  }
});
```

Now, to use this on a page, the following html will work quite well:

```
<!-- transclude will keep text of course -->
<emphasize-text>Example With Just Text</emphasize-text>

<!-- transclude also keep html tags intact -->
<emphasize-text><i>Example With Italics Tag</i></emphasize-text>

<!-- translcude will even keep angular variables intact!  -->
<emphasize-text>
  <div>This is a first div</div>
  <div>This is a {{secondVariable}} div</div>
</emphasize-text>
```

If you take a look at this plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/liRDIEy9sWoSPSHJ1oln?p=preview). Use a modern browser and "view source" on the output and you'll see what is happening. The tags are maintained exactly, angular just wraps them in "h1"! Perfectly what we wanted!

The key here is you can modify the semantics, behavior or really anything you want in html! Personally, I feel this is best suited for custom controls - not for something simple like I used it for. In fact, my example is probably a really bad one because future programmers would know what "h1" is much faster than they will know what "emphasize-text" will turn into. That said, you get the idea.

Happy customizing!